# Not going inside the Aspect in Aspect-Oriented-Programming

Tags: java, spring-boot, aop, aspectj, aspect

Hello I am new to Aspect Oriented Programming and trying to understand some concepts.
I am writing a simple Spring Boot Application where I defined a dummyEndpoint where I am calling a method of a class.  I want to apply my custom annotation to that class. My code is as follows:

Endpoint in Controller

```
@PostMapping("/dummy")
public ResponseEntity<String> dummyRequest() {
    ClassA obj = new ClassA();
    obj.consume();
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).build();
}
```

CustomAnnotation

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface custom {}
```

CustomAnnotationAspect

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class CustomAnnotationAspect {
    @Around("@annotation(custom)")
    public Object trace(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object res = null;
        System.out.println("-----ASPECT CALL--------");
        joinPoint.proceed();
        return null;
    }
}
```

ClassA.java

```
public class ClassA {
    @custom
    public void consume() {
        // actions
    } 
}
```

This code is not going into Aspect when I have a request to "/dummy". Although if I put the @custom at the endpoint level i.e. just after @PostMapping("/dummy"), it goes into aspect but in my use case I want it to be just at the method level i.e. in this case at ClassA consume method.

What I am missing here? Is there any extra config needed anywhere?

Comment: `ClassA` would need to be a spring managed bean, since aspect creates a proxy class for it.

Comment: Adding to the previous comment : Spring AOP currently supports only method execution join points (advising the execution of methods on Spring beans).  [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#aop-introduction-spring-defn) is a good place to start